# using TmParallelApply in a loop to create variables

Tags: r, for-loop, variables, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to condense this block of code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Bernie_Sentiments)) {

nrctoken <- data_frame(text = Bernie_Sentiments$text[i]) %>% unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% anti_join(stop_words) %>% inner_join(get_sentiments("nrc")) %>% count(sentiment) %>% spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0)

nrc_positive = tryCatch(nrctoken$positive, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_negative = tryCatch(nrctoken$negative, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_anger = tryCatch(nrctoken$anger, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_anticipation = tryCatch(nrctoken$anticipation, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_disgust = tryCatch(nrctoken$disgust, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_fear = tryCatch(nrctoken$fear, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_joy = tryCatch(nrctoken$joy, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_sadness = tryCatch(nrctoken$sadness, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_surprise = tryCatch(nrctoken$surprise, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)
nrc_trust = tryCatch(nrctoken$trust, warning = function(x) 0,  error = function(x) 0)

Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_positive[i] <- nrc_positive
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_negative[i] <- nrc_negative
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_anger[i] <- nrc_anger
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_anticipation[i] <- nrc_anticipation
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_disgust[i] <- nrc_disgust
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_fear[i] <- nrc_fear
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_joy[i] <- nrc_joy
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_sadness[i] <- nrc_sadness
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_surprise[i] <- nrc_surprise 
Bernie_Sentiments$nrc_trust[i] <- nrc_trust
}
```

And I have come up with this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Bernie_Sentiments)) {

 nrctoken <- data_frame(text = Bernie_Sentiments$text[i]) 
 %>% unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% anti_join(stop_words) 
 %>% inner_join(get_sentiments("nrc")) %>% 
 count(sentiment) %>% spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) 
 emotions_list <- c('positive', 'negative', 'anger', 
 'anticipation', 'disgust', 'fear', 'joy', 'sadness',
 'surprise', 'trust')

 TmParallelApply(X = emotions_list, FUN = function(x) 
 {substitute(x, Bernie_Sentiments)[i] = 
 tryCatch(substitute(x, nrctoken), warning = function(x) 
 0,  error = function(x) 0)}, export = ls(), envir = 
 environment())
}
```

However, I keep getting the error message: Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 8 nodes produced errors; first error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable. Any ideas on how I can fix or improve my code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does first code block work? I wonder about the `tryCatch` calls since it usually runs on methods which raises warnings/errors, not values like characters/numerics.

Comment: Also per `r` tag (hover or click): Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls. Specifically, provide `dput` of `Bernie_Sentiments` and include `library` sources for `TmParallelApply`, `unnest_tokens`, even `inner_join` since these are not base R methods.

Comment: Yes, the first code block works fine. Can you please explain how to use `dput()`? Would it simply be `dput(Bernie_Sentiments)`?